# Input de tipo file para obtener valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Tengo un inconveniente al obtener el valor de mi `input`:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="inputFileServer" accept="image/png"/>
```

En angular tengo:

```
var file = document.getElementById('inputFileServer').files[0];
console.log("File: ", file);
```

Obteniendo como resultado "***undefined***"

Comment: Muestra ese mensaje porque no tiene seleccionado ningún archivo por lo tanto la posición 0 será indefinida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El resultado es el esperado. Si al cargar la página no se seleccionó ningún archivo en su `input` no se podrá obtener el elemento con indice `0` ya que el `FileList` estará vacío.

Para que note el cambio podría colocar el código `Js` en una función en el evento `change`

```js
function cambiarFile(){
    const input = document.getElementById('inputFileServer');
    if(input.files && input.files[0])
        console.log("File Seleccionado : ", input.files[0]);
    
}
console.log("Sin Archivo Seleccionado " + document.getElementById('inputFileServer').files[0]);
```

```html
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="inputFileServer" accept="image/png" onchange="return cambiarFile();" />
```

Comment: Hola, y si quiero obtener la ruta completa??